# Not able to see any options for Jetpack Compose in New Project wizard of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to learn Jetpack compose, but I am not able to see any Jetpack Compose options in New Project Wizard in Android Studio.

Android Studio Version:

**android-studio-2022.2.1.19-windows.exe**

[Android Studio version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0tMK.png)

[New Project Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCK50.png)

I already had Android Studio installed, so I updated the same to flamingo version, but I was not able to see Jetpack compose options in New Project wizard.

So I uninstalled the same, and downloaded and installed latest android studio from [Google Developers Official Website](https://developer.android.com/studio).

Still I am not able to see any Jetpack compose options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detail Arda is missing is that the "Empty Activity" is @Composable by default in Android Studio Bumblebee (2021.1.1) and later. So the template you're looking for is Empty Activity.

Probably like you, since that activity description -sucks- is not very informative I also thought it was just completely empty. Instead, when I created a new project with the Empty Activity I got this:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyAppTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting("Android")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Text(
        text = "Hello $name!",
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    MyAppTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your project by selecting "Empty Activity". The flamingo version is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I could start with Empty Activity, but I want to generate boiler plate in latest as well if possible, like build scripts and all in kotlin as well.

Comment: I even installed Android Studio Preview Hedgehog, no luck with Jetpack compose, but I got an option to generate build scripts in kotlin